# Pandas warning while trying to delete column

Tags: python, pandas

```
    Item   Y1961   Y1962   Y1963   Y1964   Y1965   Y1966   Y1967   Y1968  \
8  Wheat  212139  212221  201443  217656  229353  231643  216676  220347   

    Y1969  ...    Y2004  Y2005  Y2006  Y2007  Y2008  Y2009  Y2010  Y2011  \
8  215759  ...        0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

In the dataframe above, I try to drop the column named 'Item', with the foll. command:

```
vals_bel_lux.drop('Item', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

However, this gives me the foll. warning:

```
    C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:2602: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
    A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: what is the complete traceback? and how did you get `vals_bel_lux` ?

Comment: I am guessing you got `vals_bel_lux` through some slicing.

Comment: You are right, it is coming from a slice

Comment: The slice gets me a unique Item, so I cannot drop this column before.

Comment: what are you trying to drop? Do you want a completely new dataframe from the slice and then drop the column from that dataframe?

Comment: Also, you should try without `inplace=True` , it would return the result without inplace.

Comment: Right, I am trying to create a dataframe and then drop that column. I removed inplace=True, but that is still giving same warning

Comment: Can you update the question with exactly what you are expecting and how you are creating the sliced value?

Comment: ok, your original soln worked :) if you can make it an answer, I will accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most probably you received the `vals_bel_lux` through slicing, in which case the issue is occuring because you are trying to do `inplace` drop (by passing `inplace=True` argument to `drop` method).

If all you want is a new dataframe with the column dropped, you can remove that argument and accept the new `DataFrame` that is returned. Example -

```
vals_bel_lux_new = vals_bel_lux.drop('Item', axis=1)
```